# Android - SimpleCursorAdapter

Tags: android, sqlite, simplecursoradapter

I wrote application that is downloading some data from API, then parsing it and putting into SQlite Database. The application crashes after setting SimpleCursorAdapter into list view.

```
public Cursor getCursor(){
    return mDb.query(PHOTO_TABLE,TABLE_FIELDS,null,null,null,null,null);
}
```

---

```
        PhotoDataBase db=new PhotoDataBase(getApplicationContext());
        db.open();
        for(int i=0;i<photos.size();i++){
            ContentValues value=new ContentValues();
            value.put(PhotoDataBase.KEY_ROWID,i);
            value.put(PhotoDataBase.TITLE,photos.get(i).mTitle);
            value.put(PhotoDataBase.OWNER,photos.get(i).mOwner);
            db.insertData(value);
        }
        Cursor cursor=db.getCursor();
        adapter=new SimpleCursorAdapter(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,cursor,
                new String[]{PhotoDataBase.TITLE},
                new int[]{android.R.id.text1},0);

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        db.close();
        cursor.close();
```

Comment: And what's the error?

Comment: Your adapter is using the Cursor to show the data... Why did you close it?

Comment: cricket_007 You're right. It's working now.  Thank you for response. :)